# cypress intercepting specific api call from same url

Tags: cypress

In my scenario, I am polling a specific url, let's say `http://example.com/search`.

The response code returned is 202, and when the API has finished processing the task, it will eventually return status code 200.

My question is how do I assert that I eventually got status code 200, when the URL is the same for both the 202 and 200 responses?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can to set `times` property to 2 and then wait two times:

```js
cy
  .intercept('/search', { times: 2 })
  .as('search');

// ...

cy
  .wait('@search')
  .its('response.statusCode')
  .should('eq', 200);

cy
  .wait('@search')
  .its('response.statusCode')
  .should('eq', 202);
```